# Bash delete file with two variable path not working

Tags: bash, scripts, rm

I have a bash script containing this code:

```
path=/apps/files/
ext=*.csv

rm -f $path$ext
```

This is not working. When I set -o to echo each command I see this in the output...

```
rm -f '*.csv'
```

So it's not getting the path, but I use that path variable throughout the script and it works. The only difference would be that I use it with specific file names and with commands other than rm. So something like...

```
file=abc.csv
echo "some text" >> $path$file
```

... will work perfectly.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It might help to post the complete script (or at least a more substantial portion of it)

Answer (score 0):

By not quoting the assignment

```
ext=*.csv
```

You will set `ext` to "`*.csv'" only if there are NO`.csv`files in the current directory. If the current directory has`*.csv`files`ext` will get a list of them.

For example, I have 18 `.csv` files in my home directory, and none in `~/bin`.

```
walt@bat:~(0)$ cd ~/bin
walt@bat:~/bin(0)$ ext=*.csv
walt@bat:~/bin(0)$ echo $ext
*.csv
walt@bat:~/bin(0)$ cd
walt@bat:~(0)$ ext=*.csv
walt@bat:~(0)$ echo $ext
abook15.csv abook62.csv abook8.csv abook.csv accountactivity.csv Address book headers.csv addresses.csv allphones.csv assets.csv bbook.csv Jchq-2013-08-01-2014-07-31.csv Jchq.sort.csv PCF2016Aug04.csv portfolios.csv rickdisk.csv test.csv testmoo1.csv testmoo2.csv
```

Clearly, "`$path/$ext`" will look funny.

To preclude this filename interpolation, quote your assignment:

```
ext='*.csv'
```

Comment: In both cases, the expansion of `$ext` occurs during the `echo` not during the assignment  though, surely? (compare with `echo "$ext"` for example)

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but I tried this solution and it still didn't work. I also tried rm -f "${path}"$ext which didn't work either. When this script first runs there shouldn't be any .csv files in the directory, the script creates the files, does stuff with them, and then I would like to delete them. That last part is where I'm having trouble.